# Have I become a kafir if I don't like beards?

Tags: kufr, beard

I know that every Muslim should wear a beard, but what can I do if I don't like it? Have I become a kafir? Because I have heard that dislike for at least one of the provisions of Islam is enough to fall into kufr. I don't dislike the beard, I'm just shall we say "not a fan".

Comment: I'm very interested in seeing a qualified answer. There are male people  how don't grow a beard easily, or not at all. Some people don't grow hair at all, as some kind of inheritable condition. I think they can be good Muslims. As to what I have heard, it is not about having a beard but about changing the natural appearance.

Answer (score 0):

### No.

This question is not about whether the beard is a requirement in Islam (or to what extent), but whether the feelings a person has about Islamic commands are enough to qualify as Kufr. This answer is given accordingly.

The claim that `dislike for at least one of the provisions of Islam is enough to fall into kufr` is fairly extreme. Where did this statement come from?

In verse 8:5 of the Qur'an, Allah describes an incident where a group of believers had dislike for a command given to them:

> Just as thy Lord ordered thee out of thy house in truth, **even though a party among the Believers disliked it** [al-Anfal, 8:5, Yusuf Ali translation]

Importantly, the people that disliked the command are still classified as a subset of the Believers.

Having feelings is normal and natural. Being "not a fan" of a command might be a natural inclination, but it doesn't equate to outright rejecting Allah or His command. It seems that Islam does not come from what you feel about the commands from Allah, but your understanding that the commands are based on Wisdom, and that at the end of the day, you are submissive to the command of Allah, not your own feelings.

> Fighting is prescribed for you, and ye dislike it. **But it is possible that ye dislike a thing which is good for you**, and that ye love a thing which is bad for you. But Allah knoweth, and ye know not. [Surah al-Baqarah, 2:216, Yusuf Ali translation]

> O David! We did indeed make thee a vicegerent on earth: so judge thou between men in truth (and justice): **Nor follow thou the lusts (of thy heart)**, for they will mislead thee from the Path of Allah: for those who wander astray from the Path of Allah, is a Penalty Grievous, for that they forget the Day of Account. [Surah Saad, 38:26, Yusuf Ali translation]

Answer (score -1):

To become a kafir you need to deny one of ayet from quran. People who says that one will become a kafir with cutting beards will become a kafir, because of adding another rule to islam which is "completed" by Allah.